# error: 'libavutil/internal.h' file not found

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

I'm using ffmpeg lib. 
I try `#include "libavutil/internal.h"` but received error 'libavutil/internal.h' file not found.
What should I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed ffmpeg?
First, ffmpeg is a software, not a library. It contains several libraries such as libavutil.

Then, once ffmpeg is installed, look if it's in your library path.
I suppose you're trying to compile with gcc/g++, so, you can also try to add -I[dir_where_libavutil_is]

Of course, you need `libavutil-dev` installed in your system.

Comment: Do you have two ffmpeg installations?

Comment: @Orest, if you're using linux, try installing `libavutil-dev` package

Comment: I do not use ffmpeg app. I use ffmpeg lib, as a purt of program

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg is a C application (mainly). But still support some object orientation features like information hiding (Encapsulation).

You should stick with the exposed interface (API - libav). There is a good reason for this. The header and its functions as the name suggest is "internal". Not safe to use (may change, etc..).

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: Outside of ffmpeg application, you "can't". Tell us why do you need that header (what are you trying to do?). There should be another and better way to do what you trying to do.

Comment: I want set timerstamps

Comment: Do you mean PTS/DTS values ?

Comment: Yes. I want it.

Comment: These requires some calculation based on several factors. Your best bet may be the examine some open source projects.